# Can't access to Odoo source code in docker - docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, odoo

I'm trying to access to the source code of Odoo in my project. The problem is that i need to go inside the docker container and edit the files there, this is ok but when i do a re-build of my container i lose all the contant i have edited.
This is my docker-compose service:

```
odoo:
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
command: odoo -i base
volumes:
  - ./odoo/odoo_addons:/mnt/extra-addons
  - ./odoo/config:/etc/odoo
  - ./odoo_web:/var/lib/odoo
ports:
- 8069:8069
env_file:
  - ./odoo.required.env
depends_on:
  - postgres
networks:
  - javier
restart: unless-stopped
```

The soure code is located in **/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/** so my idea is to mount a volume in that folder but when i do that i get a lot of errors. I searched in the odoo forum and other forums but i didn't find any solution.
Any sugestion will help me! Thank you!

Comment: Think of the Docker container like a RAM disk: in fact, anything you edit inside the container will be lost as soon as the container exits.  https://github.com/odoo/odoo looks like an ordinary Python project and if I was going to develop it I'd use a host-based virtual environment, leaving Docker mostly out of the picture.

Comment: I have a solution for you. If you are still looking. let me know so that i spend the time to add it here!